# How to update sqlalchemy orm object by a python dict

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy

the dict's key names are mapping to the sqlalchemy object attrs

ex:

```
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    fullname = Column(String)
    password = Column(String)
```

can update from id = 3, `{name: "diana"}` or id = 15, `{name: "marchel", fullname: "richie marchel"}`

Answer (score 78):

You can use `setattr()` to update attributes on an existing SQLAlchemy object dynamically:

```
user = session.query(User).get(someid)

for key, value in yourdict.items():
    setattr(user, key, value)
```

Comment: this is a set with a get, maybe a little bit slow?

Comment: @RichardWong: The ORM needs at least to verify that the entry exists and give the object a chance to interfere with the data (there may be hybrid properties, etc). You could create your own `UPDATE` statement with SQLAlchemy core, of course.

Comment: @RichardWong: but take into account that the session is quite sophisticated in caching and tracking updates. If you choose to bypass that you must make sure to invalidate the session cache as well.

Comment: Ooops, realized that using core directly is bypass the session cache. thank u so much.

Comment: is there any advantage of this solution of [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52316430/2223706) below using `.update(dict_)`?

Comment: @Garrett: See the [documentation on `Query.update()`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/stable/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.update); that's a bulk update procedure that bypasses the ORM. If you have, say, hybrid properties or relationships defined, those won't be updated, while `setattr()` would update those.

Answer (score 30):

I have another solution here. It would be handy to define model method as following.

```
class ModelName(db.Model):
    """
    docstring here
    """
    ...

    def update(self, **kwargs):
        for key, value in kwargs.items():
            if hasattr(self, key):
                setattr(self, key, value)
```

I hope it would solve your problem.

Thank you

Answer (score 17):

Depending on your usecase (if you don't need to validate or infer anything from the model), you can save one DB call by using `filter_by` with `id` to get a specific row, and update it using a dictionary like you initially wanted.

```
user_query = session.query(User).filter_by(id=someid)
data_to_update = dict(name="marchel", fullname="richie marchel")

user_query.update(data_to_update)
```

You might also need to add `synchronize_session=False` keyword argument to your `update` call, depending on the type of your session (if you use `scoped_session`):

```
user_query.update(data_to_update, synchronize_session=False)
```

Comment: I got "TypeError: update() got an unexpected keyword argument 'my_field'
"

Comment: I wanted to update all the properties on my obj without making a real model, and I ended up looping through properties/values of the object i wanted to update, and I added them to the updater's values dictionary, while skipping the `Id` prop. This worked really well for me so far and it's pretty dynamic.

Answer (score 5):

base on answer of @martijn-pieters, 
you can not only dynamic update column with `setattr`, but also can use dynamic table and column combine with `getattr` and `setattr`

example:

```
# models.py
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    fullname = Column(String)
    password = Column(String)

# update.py
import models

def dynamic_update(dynamic_table, col_id, dynamic_cols):
    """
    dynamic_table: name of the table, "User" for example
    col_id: id of which column you want to update
    dynamic_cols: key value pairs {name: "diana"}
    """
    if hasattr(models, dynamic_table):
        table = getattr(models, dynamic_table)
        col_info = table.query.filter_by(id=col_id).first()
        for (key, value) in dynamic_cols.items():
            if hasattr(table, key):
                setattr(col_info, key, value)
                session.commit()
```

BTW, you can get more info about `setattr`, `getattr`, `hasattr` from python offical doc
https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#setattr

https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr

https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#hasattr

Comment: doesn't look much helpful then already answered question perhaps you should explain why is it necessary that you did

Comment: @Gahan i search through the network, "how to dynamic update sqlalchemy table and column", but didn't find a good solution, and from this one, i know how to update a column dynamic, and use the above method, we can update sqlalchemy table more easily, not only dynamic column, but also dynamic table.

Comment: that's nice explaination please add it to your answer

Comment: Warning: this will `commit` on every fields change in the same model, **hurting performance significantly** (and unnecessarily) if updating several fields on the same model.

Comment: yes, for each field update, it will commit,  maybe its good to put the commit at the outer `if`, and only commit one time after all fields update.

Comment: Downvoted because 1- it has very bad performance: it makes one request per model per field, in addition to committing on every field; 2- committing on each field might break your logic if you rely on having a single transaction for all updates; 3- it has no guards if `dynamic_table` doesn’t exist or `col_id` doesn’t match; 4- this is a complicated and inefficient way of running a simple `UPDATE … WHERE`.

Answer (score 3):

In sqlalchemy 2.0 API, you can use:

```py
from sqlalchemy import update

stmt = update(User).where(User.name == "john").values(**your_data)
session.execute(stmt)
```

Answer (score 1):

I found this solution while working with flask-sqlalchemy then test it on sqlalchemy & it works as well:

```
dict = {name: "marchel", fullname: "richie marchel"}
session.execute(update(User).filter_by(id=3).values(**dict))
session.commit()
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest way is to use sqlalchemy `update` with a `filter`

```
def update_item(db: Session, item_id: int, item: ItemUpdate):
    db.query(Item).filter(id=item_id).update(item.dict())
    db.commit()
```

Ensure you are always filtering on a primary key to avoid updating more than a single row. This could be done as a check in the code before committing the session.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this helper function to update SQLAlchemy entities recursive from Pydantic.

```py
from typing import Type, TypeVar

from pydantic import BaseModel
from sqlalchemy.orm import RelationshipProperty

from backend.common.orm.models import Base

T = TypeVar('T')


def pydantic_to_sqlalchemy(
    source: BaseModel | dict,
    target: T | Type[T]
) -> Type[T]:
    if not isinstance(target, Base):
        target_class = target
        target = target_class()
    else:
        target_class = target.__class__

    if isinstance(source, dict):
        source_dict = source
    else:
        source_dict = vars(source)

    for var, value in source_dict.items():
        if not hasattr(target_class, var):
            continue

        if isinstance(value, BaseModel|dict):
            sub_target = getattr(target, var)
            if sub_target:
                value = pydantic_to_sqlalchemy(value, sub_target)
            else:
                class_attrib = getattr(target_class, var)
                if isinstance(class_attrib.property, RelationshipProperty):
                    relationship: RelationshipProperty = class_attrib.property
                    value = pydantic_to_sqlalchemy(value, relationship.argument)

        setattr(target, var, value)

    return target
```

Works like:

```py
pydantic_to_sqlalchemy(pydantic, sqlalchemy)
pydantic_to_sqlalchemy(pydantic.model_dump(), sqlalchemy)
sqlalchemy = pydantic_to_sqlalchemy(pydantic, MySQLAlchemyModel)
```

Answer (score -1):

the best solution is this:

```
    def updateContactme(data:Contactme):
    with Session(engine) as session:
        session.exec(update(Contactme).where(Contactme.id == 2).values(data.dict()))
        session.commit()
        return "ok"
```

dont forget to use .dict()