# Flask - How to save a JSON data each key to it column

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I am trying to save a JSON data automatically in database but each key should get saved in it column:

```
class Users(UserMixin, db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
    firstname = db.Column(db.String(100))
    lastname = db.Column(db.String(100))
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True)
    telephone = db.Column(db.String(15))
    fullname = db.Column(db.String(100))
    address1 = db.Column(db.String(100))
    city = db.Column(db.String(50))
    country = db.Column(db.String(50))
    region = db.Column(db.String(50))
```

JSON data is as following:

```
user_info = {
    'firstname': 'Test1', 
    'lastname': 'Test2', 
    'telephone': '1234567890', 
    'city': 'City 1', 
    'email': 'example@gmail.com', 
    'address1': 'Address', 
    'country': 'America', 
    'region': 'Whatever'
}
```

is there any way to automate that, something like:

user = Users.query.save(user_info)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only have matching fields you can use:

```
user = Users(**user_info)
```

This creates a new user. Check this out: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists

If you want to update the user with new data you can use:

```
Users.query.get(user_id).update(**user_info)
db.session.commit()
```

Comment: So all i have to do is to just unpacking the arguments and match them with columns, something like `Users.query.filter_by(**user_info)` then to commit that?

Comment: by that i am just creating a user object not saving data, am i right?

Comment: The users are changing there profiles every day, and i am not willing to do if statements every time to check if that value exist then do that, better to do is by saving there changes, i think `@classmethod` helping some where!

Comment: I added to my answer above. You can use @classmethod but it's a bit of overkill if you're only updating the data, as sqlalchemy has lots of builtins for this.

Answer (score 0):

It was as easy as drinking water.

```
user = Users.query.filter_by(id=current_user.id)

user.update(data, synchronize_session=False)
db.session.commit()
```

[How to update sqlalchemy orm object by a python dict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23152337/how-to-update-sqlalchemy-orm-object-by-a-python-dict)

[More about synchronize_session](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.delete)